# Is handle always 32bit on both 32bit and 64bit platforms?

Tags: vba, 64-bit, vsto

I need to obtain the handle of Excel 2016 64bit.

But `Application.Hwnd` returns a long , and there is no `Application.HwndPtr`.

Is it reliable?

If it's reliable, why Microsoft add `Application.HInstancePtr` instead of use the old `Application.HInstance` on 64bit platforms?

Is it possible for a window handle larger than 32bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine, the OS ensures that a window handle can never overflow a 32-bit value.  You can never have more than 65535 windows on a desktop so it is quite easy to do.  That it works this way is something you can see in COM interop declaration for a remotable window handle, visible in the WTypes.idl SDK file:

```
typedef union _RemotableHandle switch( long fContext ) u
{
    case WDT_INPROC_CALL:   long   hInproc;
    case WDT_REMOTE_CALL:   long   hRemote;
} RemotableHandle;

typedef [unique] RemotableHandle * wireHWND; 
typedef [unique] RemotableHandle * wireHMENU;
// etc..
```

Note how it is `long` for an out-of-process call, a 32-bit value.

A HINSTANCE is a very different kind of handle, a kernel handle, it certainly is 64-bit value under the hood.  Equal to the base address in memory of the module, so they were forced to add this property.

Comment: There are also some helper functions listed [here](https://www.viva64.com/en/k/0005/) that can be used to convert handles.